# Oracle SQL - intentionally output 2 rows from one source row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a large SQL statement with a new requirment to add in that has stumped me so far. 
Basically, if a row has cellA different from cellB values then ouput the row twice with some extra text. ColumnA and columnB contain old/new values for an item. But now rather than showing:

```
ITEM    OLD   NEW 
------------------      
ITEM A  123   456
```

it needs to show:

```
 ITEM        VALUE 
-------------------  
ITEM A OLD    123     
ITEM A NEW    456
```

"ITEM A NEW" is only fixed text so thats fine to produce and the old/new values are present - so they're available. I'm currently trying a `UNION ALL` to select the rows twice but the SQL is quite long and this only makes it double up and seems like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
create table test (item varchar(10), old int, new int);
insert into test values ('ITEM A', 123, 456);
insert into test values ('ITEM B', 123, 123);

select item || ' OLD' as item, old as value from test where old <> new
union all
select item || ' NEW' as item, new as value from test where old <> new

Result:
|       ITEM | VALUE |
|------------|-------|
| ITEM A OLD |   123 |
| ITEM A NEW |   456 |
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5225a/3

Comment: Thanks! This is currently the method I am using and it works - although the select statements in reality are so large i was looking ideally for a way to effectively do this in 'shorthand' rather than doubling up the text -  for ease of maintenance going forwards.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the `union all` approach but there is one more option: `unpivot`. Here is an example:

```
    select item, value
from
(   (
        select
            item,new,old
        from test where new<>old
    )
    unpivot
    (
        value
        for value_type in
            (new,old)
    )
)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5225a/16)

It all depends on your query. If you think this suits you better [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) is an article with more examples.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful to know, but as you suggested - the union all does seem like the option to go with at the moment.